# How can i add a legend to multiple pyplot histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I would like to identify the next combined histogram with a legend

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nbins=10

plt.title('Gaussian random numbers B-M')
plt.axis([-3, 3, 1, 25])
plotcos = plt.hist(coseno, nbins, alpha=.8, edgecolor = 'black',  linewidth=1)
plotsen = plt.hist(seno, nbins, alpha=.8, edgecolor = 'black',  linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

Tnx
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "next combined histogram" you mean individual legends for each histogram. Just use the `label` parameter in both your plot commands and then show the legend using `plt.legend()` as

```
plotcos = plt.hist(coseno, nbins, alpha=.8, edgecolor = 'black',  linewidth=1, label='coseno')
plotsen = plt.hist(seno, nbins, alpha=.8, edgecolor = 'black',  linewidth=1, label='seno')
plt.legend()
```

Comment: To get more help, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide a dataset and code to reproduce the problem